# Outline question

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to know how I can create just the outlines of this image. Like I only want lines of the shape.

[image]
[Source Image](http://www.uppsalacity.se/App_Themes/Default/img/UAcity_b_skyline_768.png)

---

Like this:

[image]

Comment: That's just basic vector drawing, some path operations... Perhaps you should try reading some tutorials and creating something before simply dropping a question? Then you can tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

By using Image Trace you can get the basic shape. Then on that Image Traced shape, use the 'Embed' option to extract that shape as a vector in AI. Then simply chance the fill to none and the outline to your colour.

Comment: Though if the scan is poor or the shape is very complex, or very simple, doing it by hand might be the fastest option.  Place the scanned image in the background, and manually place points where you want them, then remove the background image when you are satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Pen Tool** and draw the shapes you need.

You can place a photo or scan into Illustrator, then use it as a guide to manually create your paths. In the end, you fill the path with black and delete the placed photos.

See this question: "[How to transform an image into an “Emmys” type of logo?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/98181/3270)"